# How to modify web content using apache proxy?

Tags: apache, browser, proxy

I'm using apache server to test my browser. I want to insert some javascript to a web page, such as google.com to analyze the page content.

Other debugging methods are limited by my browser to use. So I want to modify the page contents at the proxy end.

Tank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/) is a solid web proxy with easy hooks for modifying pages on the fly. You can start with [this](http://www.ex-parrot.com/pete/upside-down-ternet.html) and change the script and hooks to modify html instead of images.

Comment: Can apache do easy this thing?

Comment: I'm not familiar with squid. I'm trying to use it. Can you explain how to filter/replace content using squid and sed?